# Using ZF2 ServiceManager to handle the MasterSlaveFeature

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, master-slave

Here is my config within my `Application module.config.php`:

```
            'service_manager' => array(
                'factories' => array(
                    'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
                    'navigation' => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory',
                    'masterSlaveFeature' => function($sm){
                        $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                        $slaveAdapter = clone $dbAdapter;
                        $feature = new Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature\MasterSlaveFeature($slaveAdapter);                
                        return $feature;                
                    },
                ),
            ),
```

Here is the problem. As you can see I create a new `MasterSlaveFeature Db Instance` every time I call the servicemanager for the `masterSlaveFeature` service.

I was thinking that a solution could be using the service manager to handle the `MasterSlaveFeature  Db Instance` but how do I pass the cloned`db adapter` to the service manager for loading the instance with the adapter?

I was thinking about making a new service that handles loading the MasterSlaveFeature instance.

Comment: why do you need to clone adapter at all? it will still use same db connection

Comment: Master slave feature is not created on each call to $sm->get(), it is shared by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you don't need to clone adapter.

Second, service manager uses shared instances by default, meaning consecutive call will return previously created instance, unless you specify in config instance is not shared.

As for what you want to achieve, you should define alias, eg `db_slave_adapter` and use that alias to fetch adapter:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'masterSlaveFeature' => function($sm){
            $dbAdapter = $sm->get('db_slave_adapter');
            $feature = new Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature\MasterSlaveFeature($dbAdapter);                
            return $feature;                
        },
    ),
),
```

Define alias in your application level configuration:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'aliases' => array(
        'db_slave_adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
    ),
),
```

when you will have real slave adapter, you will replace alias with adapter factory